Where are TransactionSecurityPolicy filters stored?
I am querying a TransactionSecurityPolicy in Workbench and it gives me the attributes of a TransactionSecurityPolicy that I created with ConditionBuilder.  however, the filter I used for the condition (apiVersion > 58.0) is nowhere to be found in the definition.  Are the filters stored in a different object?

I've been looking at Event Monitoring recently so was intrigued to take a look...
The documentation doesn't provide anything obvious and neither does a describe on the child relationships:

After messing about with the browser console and the network tab, it might be that it's stored as a flow:.

Which is queryable and you can grab the metadata (being lazy and using the dev console but you get the point to go further with it):


You are totally right.  Great catch.  (FYI, for those trying this, you can only query the Flow using the Tooling API).  Nice one, @girbot!

Now, I just have to figure out how the two are related!
